# Cannot use any thread related methods in Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm developing a sample app using Xamarin Forms. I need to perform a method on background using "InvokeInBackground" api, but I cannot access any Invoke methods (`InvokeInBackground`, `InvokeOnMainThread,` etc). It shows error "type or namespace could not be found".

Comment: Show us your code in order to identifying the problem

Comment: Sorry I fixed the issue as I inherited the class from UIViewcontroller fixes my issue. Thanks for your concern @1

Comment: Glad that you have resolved, I've posted anyway the solution so if someone has the problem can relate to it

Answer (score 1):

From Official **[Docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject.InvokeInBackground/p/MonoTouch.Foundation.NSAction/)** of XAMARIN:

```
MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject.InvokeInBackground
```

So every object that inherits from `NSObject` will have that method. In your case you fixed inheriting from `UIViewcontroller` which inehirits from `UIResponder` which inherits from `NSObject` :)

### Requirements

> Requirements Namespace: MonoTouch.Foundation
>
> Assembly: monotouch (in
>    monotouch.dll)
>
> Assembly Versions: 0.0.0.0